# C program Null Parsing

Tags: c

I have written a code to calculate the minimum number of coins using Greedy algorithm and Dynamic algorithm, but the Dynamic algorithm part doesn't work properly. There is a Null value going to array, I can't find it. Please HELP me. I need a answer as soon as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n;
int denom[]={1,2,4,5,20,25};
int coinCounter(int n);
int main(){

     printf("Please Enter a Number : ");
     scanf("%d",&n);
    int coinmin,orin,i;
    orin=n;
    i=coinmin=0;
     for(i=(sizeof(denom)/4)-1;i>=0;i--){

         coinmin =coinmin+n/denom[i];
          n=n%denom[i];
      }

    printf("Coin Min By Greedy Algorithm : %d\n",coinmin);
    printf("Dynamic Algorithm : %d\n",coinCounter(orin));
    return 0;
}

int coinCounter(int n){
    int opt[n];
    int largest[n];
    int i,j,a;
    i=j=0;
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++){

        opt[j]=10000;
         //printf("xxn");
        for(i=(sizeof(denom)/4)-1;i>=0;i--){

            if(denom[i]==j){

                opt[j]=1;
                largest[j]=j;
            }
            else if(denom[i]<j){
                a=opt[j-denom[i]]+1;
            }
            if(a<opt[j]){
                opt[j]=a;
                largest[j]=denom[i];
            }
        }

    }
     return opt[n];

}
```

I edited the Code as following, but the answer is not coming

```
int coinCounter(int n){
    int opt[n];
    int largest[n];
    int i,j,a;
    i=j=0;
    for(j=1;j<n;j++){

        opt[j]=10000;
         printf("xxn");
        for(i=(sizeof(denom)/4)-1;i>=0;i--){

            if(denom[i]==j){

                opt[j]=1;
                largest[j]=j;
            }
            else if(denom[i]<j){
                a=opt[j-denom[i]]+1;
            }
            if(a<opt[j]){
                opt[j]=a;
                largest[j]=denom[i];
            }
        }

    }
     return opt[n-1];

}
```

hey these are the results I'm Getting

```
Please Enter a Number : 8
Coin Min By Greedy Algorithm : 3
Dynamic Algorithm : 1
```

Another answer I'm getting I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
Please Enter a Number : 71
Coin Min By Greedy Algorithm : 4
Dynamic Algorithm : 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int coinCounter(int n){
    int opt[n];
    int largest[n]; <---- Don't do this. This does not work like you expect it to.
```

change to

```
int coinCounter(int n){
        int opt[n];
        int *largest = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

Edit:

Another bug with the algorithm

your variable "a" is not initialized and you are using it in if condition.

think of the case when `denom[i]>j`
your variable **"a" would not be initialized**
so depending upon what garbage value it has , results will vary
bug is here , but it shows up when you change opt allocation, because that allocation changes the condition. What I want to say is - `if (X<Y)`, depends on both X and Y. Problem is with X, but because you change Y, the condition changes and you get different result

Comment: Hey can you explain me why the previous program didn't work for me?

Comment: Index issue, remember in C and C++, index starts at 0.  Other issue is arrays size has to be compile time constant. i.e. int arr[4*12] is ok, but int arr[n] is not if n is something you are scanning. You need to use dynamic memory in this case.

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake Please don't edit the answer just to say thank you, instead you should put that as a comment. If there was any changes you did then you should edit your own question instead, explaining what you did and why.

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake, what happened? What is the condition looking at which you will say program not working? Should greedy and dynamic algorithm give the same answer, always?

Comment: @anon No for the given denomination set it has to be the same answer, But when I use malloc on both declarations the answer goes wrong again.

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake, ok. What is the source of algorithm for the dynamic case? Did you come up with the algorithm by yourself?

Comment: @Anon I got the recurrence formula and coded it up according to that, but I can't understand why does it gives correct and wrong answers when i manipulate memory allocations..

Comment: @Anon I added the full code, when I comment the first malloc statement it works fine

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake, that happens because your algorithm has a bug. It is bound to give different results. Reason being, your variable "a" is not initialized and you are using it in if condition.

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19322/discussion-between-anon-and-yasassri-chaturange-ratnayake)

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake `int largest[n];` is perfectly fine. It's a variable length array (bad name, since the length isn't variable, just a runtime-provided value, but that's what they're called). VLAs were introduced in C99 (they were mandatory there, they've been made an optional feature in C2011), if the compiler doesn't complain, it should implement VLAs and everything's dandy (unless `n` is so large that the arrays overflow the stack).

Answer (score 4):

#### 1

```
int opt[n]; // not the right way to do dynamic allocation. Use malloc/calloc
int largest[n];
```

#### 2

```
for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
          ^ array is indexed from 0...n-1, index-n is outside array bounds
```

**Don't do this.**

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply I edited the code like this, but still there is a error I can't figure it out,

Comment: Thanks Mate that was the issue,,Thank you so much, Really appreciate your help...:)